# ExtJS How pass a object in extraParams AjaxRequest

Tags: object, extjs, parameters

How could an object pass through the extraParams property in ExtJS?

What I am trying to do is something similar to the following:

```
extraParams: {
                    filter: {
                        region: 1,
                        active: true
                    }
                }
```

but I only get the following on my backend:

```
array:1 [
  "filter" => "true"
]
```

**EDIT 1:**
For now I have achieved it with the following:

```
extraParams: {
                    filter: Ext.encode({
                        region: 1,
                        active: true
                    })
                }
```

and in the backend:

```
json_decode($request->get('filter');
```

Comment: Can you show more from your server-side script - I suppose it's PHP. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.stringify() should work, as long as you don't have any referential loops inside.

Answer (score 1):

You can encode it to a JSON string and decode it on the backend, as you have done.

Another possiblity is to pass the object to the `jsonData` attribute.